# How to fill big holes that Meshmixer couldn't inspect?

Tags: 3d-models, meshmixer

How to fill these holes in mandibular jaw in order to 3d print it?

[image]

Comment: i've manually edited meshes of .stl before.  I used FreeCAD to do it.  pretty time consuming though so there might be a better way these days.

Comment: Have you tried using Windows 10 3DBuilder? Those areas are not so severe as to fail in 3DBuilder, from my experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used meshmixer, but both blender and meshlab have features to repair non-manifold meshes, including a way to manually fix large holes.

With both of these packages, you can have it select holes, and then either attempt to fill them automatically (which frequently gives terrible results), or manually select a few edges of a specific hole and add a few triangles at a time until it is fully covered (which gives much better results if you choose edges carefully).